# Как сделать, чтобы метод вызывался у свойства экземпляра?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Решаю задачу, в которой необходимо создать декоратор класса, который бы обладал методом `get_change` для определения было ли изменено свойство экземпляра класса или нет. Я накарябал вот такую ерунду, и в принципе оно даже можно сказать работает.
Я бы хотел узнать, можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы данный метод работал напрямую, т.е. вызывать его следующим образом: `экземпляр_класса.свойство_экземпляра_класса.get_change()` .Без всяких аргументов внутри метода.

```
def change_detection(cls):
    class NewClass:
        changes = {}

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            pass

        def __setattr__(self, key, value):
            if not hasattr(self, key):
                super().__setattr__(key, value)
                type(self).changes[key] = 'I am newborn'
            else:
                super().__setattr__(key, value)
                type(self).changes[key] = 'I have been modified already'

        def get_change(self, key):
            return type(self).changes[key]

    return NewClass


@change_detection
class DecorateMe:

    def __init__(self):
        pass


a = DecorateMe()

a.y = 5
a.y = 6
a.x = 'some string'

print(a.get_change('y')) #I have been modified already
print(a.get_change('x')) #I am newborn
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это можно реализовать с помощью дескрипторов.

```
class StateMon:
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return instance.__dict__[self.name]

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        cur_value = instance.__dict__.get(self.name)
        instance.__dict__[f"old_{self.name}"] = cur_value
        instance.__dict__[self.name] = value


class Foo():
    a = StateMon()


f = Foo()
f.a = 10
print("Old:", f.old_a, "Current: ", f.a)
# Old: None Current:  10
f.a = 90
print("Old:", f.old_a, "Current: ", f.a)
# Old: 10 Current:  90
print(type(f.a))
# <class 'int'>
```

Таким образом мы можем контролировать доступ к атрибуту так как нам вздумается.

Еще пример когда мы храним историю изменения объекта и можем по ней откатываться

```
import functools


class StateMon:
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self._states = []
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return instance.__dict__[self.name]

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        cur_value = instance.__dict__.get(self.name)
        self._states.append(cur_value)
        instance.__dict__[f"prev_{self.name}"] = functools.partial(self.prev, instance, self.name)
        instance.__dict__[self.name] = value

    def prev(self, instance, name):
        if not self._states:
            return
        instance.__dict__[self.name] = self._states.pop()


class Foo:
    a = StateMon()


f = Foo()
f.a = 10
f.a = 90
print(f.a)
# 90
f.prev_a()
print(f.a)
# 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, может в последних версиях `Python` и добавили методы расширения для стандартных классов, но насколько пишут в старых ответах на английском SO так сделать невозможно: [ссылка1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/514101/8324991), [ссылка2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7139148/8324991).

> You can add whatever methods you like on class objects defined in
> Python code (AKA monkey patching):

```
>>> class A(object):
>>>     pass

>>> def stuff(self):
>>>     print self

>>> A.test = stuff
>>> A().test()
```

> This does not work on builtin types, because their **dict** is not
> writable (it's a dictproxy). So no, there is no "real" extension
> method mechanism in Python.

Проблема в том, что у вас в свойствах лежат стандартные типы `Python` - например, `int` или `str` и метод вы хотите вызывать от них, а это значит, что вы хотите сделать метод расширения для стандартного класса, что невозможно.

По идее, если вы сделаете класс-обёртку, и будете класть в свойства экземпляра класса не исходные данные (стандартные классы `Python`), а эту обёртку, то у неё можно написать такой метод. Не знаю, может правда потом возникнут проблемы при использовании таких свойств, если от них будет ожидаться поведение и свойства стандартных классов, а там придёт эта обёртка со своим поведением и свойствами. В общем, дальше надо ещё думать, я так не соображу сразу можно ли сделать эту обёртку достаточно прозрачной. Но простого метода тут вроде нет.